# squid3 can't access google.com or bing.com

Tags: squid

I've a strange problem with squid3. It is normally working and I can access most web sites through the proxy. However some sites like

```
google.com
bing.com
```

just seem to get blocked but not always. Restarting squid3 doesn't seem to help or either clearing the /var/spool/squid3 ( cache ) directory.

If I login to the machine that squid3 is running on and

```
wget --no-proxy google.com
```

then there is no problem however if I wget through the proxy it never responds. Most other websites are accessible including stackoverflow.com which I am using through the proxy right at this moment. Any idea what might be special about google.com and bing.com so that squid3 is treating them differently and is there any setting in the squid3 conf file that might be related to such behaviour.

Comment: Just for info. google.com is working again. It seems an intermittent problem.

Comment: What does exactly happen when you open the sites? And what do you see in squid's log when making the request?

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem. I figure out my problem was caused by the IPv6 connectivity issue.

Squid3 supports both IPv6 and IPv4 protocols. If your server can't connect over IPv6 and the remote server prefers IPv6 then squid also chose the IPv6 protocol but since you network does not operate with IPv6 Squid can not retrieve data like access logs.

First, to make sure the issue is the same, try ipv6 connectivity with ping.

```
ping6 ivp6.google.com
```

If ping does not respond, let's configure squid3 for prefer IPv4 by following the below actions.

Search the line below in squid.conf

```
TAG: dns_v4_first
```

After the line below;

```
#Default:
#dns_v4_first off
```

Add this flag below;

```
dns_v4_first on
```

Then restart the Squid3 server

```
service squid3 restart
```

Here is my access log before the fix.

```
1352760882.854    796 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js [squiduser] DIRECT/connect.facebook.net -
1352760885.717     69 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google.com.tr/complete/search? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google.com.tr -
1352760886.250     13 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google.com.tr/complete/search? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google.com.tr -
1352760887.011    369 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google.com.tr/complete/search? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google.com.tr -
1352760887.989     42 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google.com.tr/complete/search? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google.com.tr -
1352760888.984     75 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google.com.tr/complete/search? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google.com.tr -
1352760897.351   8165 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google.com.tr/search? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google.com.tr -
1352761072.531  10970 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif? [squiduser] DIRECT/www.google-analytics.com -
1352761072.533  10272 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js [squiduser] DIRECT/apis.google.com -
1352761072.535  10262 88.my.ip.108 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js [squiduser] DIRECT/connect.facebook.net -
```

Here is my full squid configuration. I use squid as an anonymous proxy server.

```
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing Configuration File: /etc/squid3/squid.conf (depth 0)
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/squid.passwd
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: auth_param basic children 5
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: acl manager proto cache_object
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: acl CONNECT method CONNECT
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: http_access allow manager localhost
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: http_access deny manager
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: http_access allow localhost
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: acl ncsaauth proxy_auth REQUIRED
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: http_access allow ncsaauth
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: http_access deny all
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: http_port 8880
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: refresh_pattern ^ftp:      1440    20% 10080
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: refresh_pattern ^gopher:   1440    0%  1440
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0    0%  0
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: refresh_pattern .      0   20% 4320
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: dns_v4_first on
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: forwarded_for delete
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Allow allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Authorization allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Cache-Control allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Content-Length allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Content-Type allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Date allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Expires allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Host allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Last-Modified allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Location allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Pragma allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Accept allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Accept-Language allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Content-Language allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Mime-Version allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Retry-After allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Title allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Connection allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access User-Agent allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access Cookie allow all 
2012/11/14 00:09:02| Processing: request_header_access All deny all
```

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: Wow wow thanks !... adding `dns_v4_first on`  solved my problem!

Comment: Thanks! I know this is an old topic, but it is still solving problems.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that dns_v4_first on only works in newer squid3 versions.
If you run for example a debian6 server, you have squid3-3.1.6 which does not have this config switch.

For those older versions you have to edit the config line

```
tcp_outgoing_address SERVERIP all
```

Where SERVERIP is the IP of your server.